# Deploying to Rackspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, server-side, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Having trouble deploying to Rackspace servers. Curious if I'm missing something in my config files. I haven;t changed them since I created the app and have been looking everywhere online but can't find a solution.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what's causing problems? Application logs, outputs, etc. Right now, there's nothing to go on for helping you.

Comment: I'm not sure where to get my secret_key_base for my secrets.yml file

Answer (score 1):

The `secret_key_base` is used to securely sign the cookies that Rails creates. It needs to be set to some suitably long, arbitrary String that's different for each Rails deployment and kept secret.

What I usually do to generate a new one is run something like this:

```
ruby -rsecurerandom -e 'p SecureRandom.hex(32)'
```

... and then copy and paste that into my `secrets.yml`, in the section matching the `RAILS_ENV`:

```
production:
  secret_key_base: '553e8330b465c2c51789a8f957932e7c8d9144a5e1b93431d2db7b6bd9b681f6'
```